# Avast Antivirus has a strange version number

Tags: anti-virus

Avast! Free antivirus shows the version as 111101-3

Is this correct, or am I a target of fake software?

Comment: Could this perhaps be a `yymmdd-build` format? This might then mean the 3rd update on the 1st of November, 2011. (the date is somewhat unusual, yes :))

Comment: Thats not a standard way to show version no. Are you sure it is version no and not something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're absolutely sure you downloaded the application from the vendors website and not a third party location then I'm sure you're fine.

After a quick search on the Avast forums here: http://forum.avast.com/index.php?action=search it would appear that the number you are quoting pertains to the definition version number and not the applicaton itself.

So on the surface of it, you appear to be safe although some users over there are experiencing some issues with this particular definition update.